# Select record based on date with MS Access

Tags: java, ms-access

Initially I have a specific column to store `age` in my Table and I use the following to perform the select query

```
select count(*) from DonorDetails where age < 25
```

Now I have removed the age column and used `dob` column (with Date/Time datatype) instead. How should I write the count query which gives the same result as before ?

Comment: Is that Java tag intentional? Because if it is, presumably use of VBA functions like `DateSerial` or `DateDiff` are out...?

Comment: `DateSerial` and `DateDiff` functions can be used in Access SQL any time regardless of the client environment from which the query is executed.

Comment: I accepted @Wayne answer. I believe it's Java since it works for me :S

Comment: @HansUp. +1 Thanks for the information and effort :)

Comment: @HansUp - I stand corrected! Just tried it myself in another non-Access environment...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a sample of how your SQL should look:

```
SELECT count(*)
FROM DonorDetails 
WHERE (((DateDiff("yyyy",[dob],Date()))>25));
```

Comment: cc: @abiieez For calculating a person's age this query will give incorrect results if the person has not yet reached their birthday in the current year. For example, today's date is `2014-02-22` so someone born on `2004-12-22` is still 9 years old (in fact, they turned 9 just two months ago) but `DateDiff("yyyy", DateSerial(2004, 12, 22), Date)` returns `10`. In other words, `DateDiff("yyyy", date1, date2)` is really just another way of writing `Year(date2) - Year(date1)`.

Answer (score 3):

In the Immediate window, you can use `DateSerial` with a mix of other date functions to give you the date 25 years ago from today.

```vb
? DateSerial(Year(Date()) - 25, Month(Date()), Day(Date()))
2/22/1989
```

So in your query maybe you want something like ...

```sql
WHERE [DOB] > DateSerial(Year(Date()) - 25, Month(Date()), Day(Date()))
```

Comment: +1 cc: @abiieez For calculating a person's age, this is the correct answer because it takes the actual *date* of birth into account (not just the *year* of birth).